# How to delay jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, animation, delay

I can't seem to delay the showing of a div. I want to delay the animation by about 20 seconds is this possible???

```
$("#microcharcounter").delay(10000).show();
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#microcharcounter").delay(10000).show(0);
```

or this:

```
$("#microcharcounter").delay(10000).queue(function(n) {
    $(this).show();
    n();
});
```

The reason for this is that `.delay()` will only delay items in an animation queue. So you can make `.show()` a short animation by adding a duration of '0', or add it to the queue with [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

Comment: @Nick - Just added `n();`, but is it necessary when it is the last item?

Comment: Yup, if you ever call another animation later for example, best to be safe IMO, alternatively you can call `$(this).show().dequeue()`, that's what I tend to do when dealing with `$(this)`, a bit cleaner to me anyway.

Comment: @Nick - Ah, I see. Just did a test, and it does block the queue indefinitely. Thanks for the tip. :o)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver [from the jquery.queue docs](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback-next-) it look like a function passed to your callback that will dequeue the next item, or in this case I guess it's dequeuing that particular function (containing the `$(this).show()`) so that it's no longer on the queue and any animations that come later will run correctly.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#microcharcounter").show();
}, 20000);
```

The problem with [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) (without a duration), is that `.show()` isn't an animation, it's an immediate effect that's not on the `fx` queue at all.  You could however give it a duration, like this:

```
$("#microcharcounter").delay(20000).show("fast");
```

Comment: Always searching for delay on google when i need to use setTimeout. So this post has helped me a few times :)