# How to maintain time intervals between animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

To explain my question I have created this http://jsfiddle.net/Jams/XNVB2/ here I want when `div1` complete its 25% animation then `div2` should start its animation and when `div1` complete its 50% animation then `div3` should start its animation.

Here is jquery code

```
$("#div1").animate({width:400},2000);
$("#div2").animate({width:400},2000);
$("#div3").animate({width:400},2000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3583942

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/XNVB2/1/

```
$("#div1").animate({
    width: 400
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#div2").animate({
        width: 400
    }, 2000);
}, 500);
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#div3").animate({
        width: 400
    }, 2000);
}, 1000);
```

Alternately, you could also do this with `queue`: http://jsfiddle.net/XNVB2/2/

```
var animLength = 2000;
$("#div1").animate({width:400},animLength);
$("#div2").delay(animLength * 0.25).queue(function(n){
    $(this).animate({width:400},animLength);
    n();
});
$("#div3").delay(animLength * 0.5).queue(function(n){
    $(this).animate({width:400},animLength);
    n();
});
```

​

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. Your answer is good. Please tell me one thing Is there no function in jquery (instead of setTimeout)?

Comment: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation) one animation is executing after first one is completed, but in my case all animations executing at same time? sorry for another question.

Comment: In the link you just posted, the animations are automatically queued up because they're all on the same element.

Comment: You are there because you deserve it. You will earn many more in future.