# jQuery: Staggered animation on list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation container with vertically ordered links inside.  What I would like is for each link to fade in and fly from left to right.  I am not sure however how to do this sequentially? I have code that does them all at once but I want to do them one at a time. Or at least have them staggered so there is an arbitary delay between animations firing

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation a")
        .css({opacity:0,"margin-right":"10px"})
        .animate({opacity:1,"margin-right":"0"});
});
```

Comment: something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583942/how-to-delay-jquery-animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

As Nate commented below, `arguments.callee` is deprecated. Although [not everyone agrees on this matter](http://mir.aculo.us/2012/04/24/5-things-they-told-you-not-to-use-in-javascript/), generally deprecated functionality should be avoid. Thanks to Nate, the following will work without using `arguments.callee`.

**Working Example:** http://jsbin.com/idizi/1359/edit

```
var paras = $('p'),
    i = 0;

// If using jQuery 1.3 or lower, you need to do 
// $(paras[i++] || []) to avoid an "undefined" error
function animateNav () {
    $(paras[i++]).fadeIn('fast', animateNav)
                 .css({opacity:0,"margin-left":"10px"})
                 .animate({opacity:1,"margin-left":"0"});
}

animateNav();
```

---

This will get the desired result.

**Working Example:** http://jsbin.com/idizi/1356/edit

```
var paras = $('p'),
        i = 0;

// If using jQuery 1.3 or lower, you need to do 
// $(paras[i++] || []) to avoid an "undefined" error
(function() {
  $(paras[i++]).fadeIn('fast', arguments.callee)
               .css({opacity:0,"margin-right":"10px"})
               .animate({opacity:1,"margin-right":"0"});
})();
```

via http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-easy-sequential-animations-in-jquery/

Comment: This is extremely clever. Note, though, that arguments.callee is deprecated in EC5 strict. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee

Comment: I didn't realize it was deprecated. Trying to find a way around using it.

Comment: Just use a named function rather than an anonymous one. http://jsbin.com/idizi/1359/edit

Comment: Thanks for the update - I like the link to Fuch's argument, too. I strongly disagree with him (strict mode opts you in to the language features that will be carried forward, which is a very good idea), but that is, as you say, a contested matter.

I like the example at the end, but am left feeling it would be better without the ++ magic, and without the silent failing out when i exceeds the number of paragraphs. http://jsbin.com/idizi/1361/edit This way, everything is nice and explicit.

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect use for $.queue. Thanks for the question: you made me learn how to use it a little better to research this.

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/EJgEC/

```
// Cache our jQuery-wrapped objects
var $navigation = $('#navigation'),
    $navigationLinks = $navigation.find('a');

// Set the initial state on navigation links for future animation
$navigationLinks.css({
  opacity: 0,
  "margin-left": "20px"
});

$navigationLinks.each(function (i, item) {
  var $item = $(item);

  // Add animations on each item to the fx queue on the navigation DOM element
  $.queue($navigation[0], 'fx', function () {
    var that = this;
    $item.animate({
      opacity: 1,
      "margin-left": "0"
    }, {
      complete: function () {
        // Fire the next item in the queue as the callback
        $.dequeue(that);
      }
    });
  });
});

// Start the navigation queue
$navigation.dequeue();
```

I also highly suggest reading up on $.queue: it's worth knowing about. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/

Comment: Thanks Nate, very good answer but I decided to go with something similar to what Jsuar suggested. But gave you +1

Comment: Thanks! I still recommend learning about $.queue, but since I like JSuar's answer, too, I can't fault you too much. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var links =  $("#navigation a");
   var count = 0;

   var handle = setInterval(function(){
         $(links[count])
            .css({opacity:0,"margin-right":"10px"})
            .animate({opacity:1,"margin-right":"0"});
             count++;

             if(count==links.length){
                  clearInterval(handle);
              }                

    }, 5000);



});
```

Comment: I can't speak for whoever voted it down, but not clearing the setInterval when you're done with it is very bad practice. It's gonna keep on firing till doomsday.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-jQuery-dependent solution.

The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N9afT/

```
   function stagger(targets, interval, action){
    for (var i = 0, maxi = targets.length; i < maxi; i++) {
        (function(){
            var target = targets[i];
            setTimeout(function(){action(target);}, interval*i);
        })();
    }
   }
```

example:

```
stagger([1, 2, 3], 1000, function(val){console.log(val)})
```

But of course, it can also be applied to jquery targets.

```
stagger($(".element-class"), 1000, function(el){console.log(el)})
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents on the topic as well, since I was looking for an idea too. I came up with this for my case:

```js
// in On-Ready wrapper

$('nav li')
.hide(0)   // instant, no animation, 
.each(function (i) {
  $(this)
    .delay(i * 400)    // stagger the following animation
    .fadeIn("slow");
});
```

In the context of the question above, this would look like

```js
// in On-Ready wrapper

$('#navigation a')
.css({opacity: 0, marginRight: '10px'}) 
.each(function (i) {
  $(this)
    .delay(i * 400)    // stagger the following animation
    .animate({opacity: 1, marginRight: 0});
});
```

This works, because `.each(cb(index))` gives us an index for each child, and the children get a delay and an animation (in that order) added to their [FX-Queue](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) :)

Btw, instead of `.delay()` you can use the `.animate({}, options={delay: 123})` delay to set it.