# slider won't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate my list item towards right but it animate all item towards right at once but I want it to be one after another ..here is my jQuery

```
var I,
    total_slide = $('#slide li').length,
    slide = $('#slide li');

function run() {
  for (I = 1; I <= total_slide; I++) {
    var total = total_slide - I
    $(slide).eq(total).animate({
      left: '700px'
    }, 4000);
  }
}

run()
```

Comment: `eq(l)` should have to be there and l should have initial value of 0.

Comment: I have tried that but that slides first three  list at once what I dnt want .I want it to be one after another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Staggered animation on list of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183899/jquery-staggered-animation-on-list-of-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setTimeout` function to make pauses between animations:

```
function run(){
    var timeout = 0, delay = 4000;
    $("#slide li").each(function(){
        var $li = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $li.animate({ left: 700 }, delay);
        }, timeout);
        timeout += delay;
    });
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rc1awn2o/)

Also I would recommend to use CSS-animations whenever it's possible:

[Example with CSS-animations](https://jsfiddle.net/rc1awn2o/1/)

Comment: How do I slide it back to the original position after sliding to right ?

Comment: Just execute `$("#slide li").css("left", 0);`

Comment: Done it but it animate the first li back to its original position however the rest of the li starts slides after the first one gets back its position ..I want all the li to animate left first then get em all back to their original position one by one ..