# How to delay a j-query rotation animation

Tags: jquery, rotation, delay

I have a div element rotating back and forth a set number of times, using the following code:

plug-in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var rotation = function (times) {
var el = $("#pencil");
if(typeof times == 'number'){
    el.data('repeatRotation',times);
} else {
    times = el.data('repeatRotation')-1;
    el.data('repeatRotation',times);
}
if(times > 0){
    $("#pencil").rotate({
        angle: 0,
        animateTo: 2,
        duration: 200,
        callback: rotationBack
    });
}
}
var rotationBack = function () {
$("#pencil").rotate({
    angle: 0,
    animateTo: -2,
    duration: 200,
    callback: rotation
});
}
rotation(10);
});
```

What I actually want is the div element to start roatating after a 5 second delay. I tried adding the usual .delay(5000) to the above code, as shown below, but it does not seem to make a difference, the code still executes immediately after the page loads:

```
if(times > 0){
    $("#pencil").delay(5000).rotate({
        angle: 0,
        animateTo: 2,
        duration: 200,
        callback: rotationBack
    });
```

Does anyone know why the .delay(5000) is not working in this case?

Comment: `.rotate()` isnt in the jQuery library. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: sorry yes, the plug-in used for this is:    

<script type="text/javascript"src="http//jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>

I've now added this to the question

Comment: That plugin probably doesn't use jQuery FX queue, so delay() won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)only works on objects in a queue. If it is not working for that plugin it means they did not implement their animations in such a way that they were added to a jQuery queue. it is easy enough to add this functionality in using `setTimeout` though

```
if (times > 0) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#pencil").rotate({
            angle: 0,
            animateTo: 2,
            duration: 200,
            callback: rotationBack
        });
    }, 5000);
```

to add the delay to just the first rotation change your code from

`rotation(10);`

to

```
setTimeout(function(){
    rotation(10);
},5000);
```

Comment: Thanks DGS - this works, however it delays each individual rotation cycle by 5 seconds. So the div rotates back and forth once, then waits 5 seconds, then rotates back and forth again, then waits 5 seconds...etc. Ideally Im after it waiting 5 seconds, then rotating back and forth 10 times with no delay between each rotation. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The reason `delay` is not working for you is because initially there is nothing in the animation queue to delay.

To fix this you need to queue your `.rotate` call:

```
$('#pencil').delay(4000).queue(function(){

  $(this).rotate({
    angle: 0,
    animateTo: 2,
    duration: 200,
    callback: rotationBack
  });

});
```

Have a look at <kbd>[this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oWiRIle/1)</kbd> for an example.

Also take a look at this question [How to delay jquery animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583942/how-to-delay-jquery-animation).