# Image display in sequence with animation and delay (fade-in and slide-up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fadein, slideup

**I'm trying to cycle three images with these effects:**

1. One second delay before showing first image
2. Image #1 is displayed with a fade-in and slide up effect.
3. Image #1 is shown for 5 seconds and then fades out.

[process repeats after this point...]

4. One second delay before next image starts.
5. Image #2 is displayed with the same fade-in and slide up effect, shown for 5 seconds, fades out... and the process is repeated for Image #3 and loops continuously in same pattern.

**This is what I have built so far:** http://jsfiddle.net/27uy8/226/
runslide();

```
function runslide() {
 $('#pic1').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'slow'}).animate({ top: "-100px" }, 'slow').delay(3500).fadeOut(1500, function() {                  
    $('#pic2').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'slow'}).animate({ top: "-100px" }, 'slow').delay(3500).fadeOut(1500, function() {
            $('#pic3').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'slow'}).animate({ top: "-100px" }, 'slow').delay(3500).fadeOut(1500, function() {
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**I'm running into two issues:**

1) when the slide restarts, it looses it's slide up animation.

2) I don't know how to add a blank one second delay before starting each image.

I hope someone here can help me! Sorry if the code is not the cleanest, this is my first time working with image animations.

Comment: Regarding the position on the second execution, you animate the top to -100 but never reset it to zero. To fix reset top for pics to 0.

Comment: Regarding the initial delay: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583942/how-to-delay-jquery-animation

Comment: I know you already accepted the answer. I was working on different type of solution. This might also help you. Uses CSS3 animation with Javascript. Here is the link -http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgEOqX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messed with your timings slightly to speed it up. Important points are

```
 $('#pic1,#pic2,#pic3').css({top: 0})
```

to reset positions

and

```
 $('#pic1').delay(3500).fadeIn({queue: true, ....
```

to delay start / between repeats.

Based on your JSFiddle...

```js
runslide();

function runslide() {
  $('#pic1,#pic2,#pic3').css({top: 0})
  $('#pic1').delay(3500).fadeIn({queue: true, duration: 'slow'}).animate({ top: "-100px" }, 'slow').delay(3500).fadeOut(1500, function() {          
    $('#pic2').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'slow'}).animate({ top: "-100px" }, 'slow').delay(3500).fadeOut(1500, function() {
         $('#pic3').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'slow'}).animate({ top: "-100px" }, 'slow').delay(3500).fadeOut(1500, function() {
            runslide();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

```css
#pics div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
#pics {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pics">
  <div id="pic1">
    <img src="http://www.sbwebsitesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/step1blue-300x300.png">
  </div>
  <div id="pic2">
    <img src="http://www.sbwebsitesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/step2blue-300x300.png">
  </div>
  <div id="pic3">
    <img src="http://www.sbwebsitesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/step3blue-300x300.png">
  </div>
</div>
```